# Coroutine fails with firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I recieve data from realtime db firebase and emit it in flow I collected noting and get an error.
There is a data in database, it collecting by cycle from datasnaphot, but dont collect outside from there

```
class PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(): PizzaStoreRepository {


    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)



    private val citiesFlow = flow {
        val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val dRef = database.getReference("cities")

        val listCities = mutableListOf<City>()

        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val key: String = data.key ?: continue
                    val value = data.getValue<String>() ?: continue
                    listCities.add(City(key.toInt(), value))
                }
                scope.launch {
                    emit(listCities)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("TEST_TEST", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        dRef.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }



    override suspend fun getCitiesUseCase(): Flow<List<City>> {
        return citiesFlow
    }
}
```

```
interface PizzaStoreRepository {

    suspend fun getCitiesUseCase(): Flow<List<City>>

}
```

```
class GetCitiesUseCase  @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PizzaStoreRepository
) {

    suspend fun getCities(): Flow<List<City>> {
        return repository.getCitiesUseCase()
    }
}
```

```
class CityDeliveryViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getCitiesUseCase: GetCitiesUseCase
): ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<CityDeliveryScreenState>(CityDeliveryScreenState.Initial)
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val citiesFlow = getCitiesUseCase.getCities().stateIn(this)
            citiesFlow
                .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
                .collect {
                _state.emit(CityDeliveryScreenState.ListCities(it))
            }
        }
    }

    fun changeState(state: CityDeliveryScreenState) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.emit(state)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
@Parcelize
data class City(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val deliveryType: DeliveryType = DeliveryType.TAKE_OUT
) : Parcelable
```

`Process: com.example.pizzastore, PID: 3466 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flow invariant is violated: Emission from another coroutine is detected. Child of StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@e823ba3, expected child of StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@eb13ea0. FlowCollector is not thread-safe and concurrent emissions are prohibited. To mitigate this restriction please use 'channelFlow' builder instead of 'flow' at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector_commonKt$checkContext$result$1.invoke(SafeCollector.common.kt:68) at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector_commonKt$checkContext$result$1.invoke(SafeCollector.common.kt:25) at kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$Element$DefaultImpls.fold(CoroutineContext.kt:70) at kotlinx.coroutines.Job$DefaultImpls.fold(Job.kt:112) at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.fold(JobSupport.kt:27) at kotlin.coroutines.CombinedContext.fold(CoroutineContextImpl.kt:131) at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector_commonKt.checkContext(SafeCollector.common.kt:25) at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.checkContext(SafeCollector.kt:106) at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:83) at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:66) at com.example.pizzastore.data.repository.PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl$citiesFlow$1$postListener$1$onDataChange$1.invokeSuspend(PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl.kt:39) at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664) Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@e823ba3, Dispatchers.IO]`

I've used advise from log, but it did'nt help me

Changes:

```
private val citiesFlow = channelFlow<List<City>> {
        val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val dRef = database.getReference("cities")

        val listCities = mutableListOf<City>()

        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val key: String = data.key ?: continue
                    val value = data.getValue<String>() ?: continue
                    listCities.add(City(key.toInt(), value))
                }
                scope.launch {
                    send(listCities)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("TEST_TEST", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        dRef.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }
```

Error:
`Process: com.example.pizzastore, PID: 3564 kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedSendChannelException: Channel was closed at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Closed.getSendException(AbstractChannel.kt:1107) at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.helpCloseAndResumeWithSendException(AbstractChannel.kt:230) at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.access$helpCloseAndResumeWithSendException(AbstractChannel.kt:19) at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.sendSuspend(AbstractChannel.kt:220) at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.send(AbstractChannel.kt:136) at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ChannelCoroutine.send(Unknown Source:2) at com.example.pizzastore.data.repository.PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl$citiesFlow$1$postListener$1$onDataChange$1.invokeSuspend(PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl.kt:40) at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677) at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664) Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@872eeff, Dispatchers.IO]`

Also I tried to get it with creating MutableStateFlow outside of citiesFlow in PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl:

1. App didnt crash
2. Collect in viewModel dosent work, but only init value
3. when I tried to collect value in the same scope in PizzaStoreRepositoryImpl, it dont collect but only init value

Litle bit earlier error has nullpointer exception, now dont

Comment: Too lazy to write a proper answer but take a look at https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html

usage: https://proandroiddev.com/callbackflow-with-firebase-converting-realtimedatabase-callbacks-into-callbackflow-b40461444c9a

Answer (score 1):

The glaring problem is your use of a MutableList and emitting the same instance over and over. (There could be other issues, but you provided a lot of code to go through and I haven't scrutinized all of it.)

The problem with emitting the same List instance repeatedly is that if you conflate  the emissions (i.e. filter out emissions that repeat the previous value), they will all be considered the same value (a List instance always equals itself--there is no history to compare it to), so nothing will be emitted after the first item.

And by using StateFlow or State downstream, you are conflating emissions. Both of these use conflation under the hood.

The quick and dirty fix is to replace `emit(listCities)` in your source Flow with `emit(listCities.toList())`. You probably do not want to fix this by avoiding StateFlow/State. Conflation is a good thing because it avoids wasting resources on redundant tasks.

---

Side note, you should use `callbackFlow` instead of `flow` for reacting to a callback, so your flow can properly handle cancellation. `callbackFlow` will help force you to properly dispose of the listener when the Flow collection is cancelled. Your current implementation is leaking the listener every time this Flow is collected.

Actually, I'd be surprised if Firebase doesn't already provide a way to get a Flow already built properly for you. Some function like `asFlow()`, but I don't use Firebase so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

With advise about callbackflow by **Tenfour04** my problem was resolve.

```
        private val citiesFlow = callbackFlow {
            val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            val dRef = database.getReference("cities")

            val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val listCities = mutableListOf<City>()
                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val key: String = data.key ?: continue
                        val value = data.getValue<String>() ?: continue
                        listCities.add(City(key.toInt(), value))
                    }
                    val returnList = listCities.toList()
                    trySend(returnList)
                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.w("TEST_TEST", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
                }
            }
            dRef.addValueEventListener(postListener)

            awaitClose {
                dRef.removeEventListener(postListener)
            }
        }
```